# Magnolia 5.4 upgrade java.nio.file.InvalidPathException on publishing/unpublishing

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

When I tried to upgrade to magnolia 5.4 from 5.3.9 or download magnolia bundle with tomcat from official website and just run it, on publishing/unpublishing I receive:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-68" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 48: C:\dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\mg-auth\/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/af/72/95/af72957c-bb65-4132-881c-205eee9e68f3/1.12
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at info.magnolia.resourceloader.file.FileSystemResourceOrigin.getPath(FileSystemResourceOrigin.java:241)
    at info.magnolia.resourceloader.file.FileSystemResourceOrigin.hasPath(FileSystemResourceOrigin.java:139)
    at info.magnolia.resourceloader.util.Functions$1.apply(Functions.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.resourceloader.util.Functions$1.apply(Functions.java:57)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:652)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.hasNext(TransformedIterator.java:43)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.addAll(Iterators.java:361)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:160)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:144)
    at info.magnolia.resourceloader.layered.LayeredResourceOrigin.getByPath(LayeredResourceOrigin.java:96)
    at info.magnolia.resourceloader.layered.RelayerResourceVisitor.visitFile(RelayerResourceVisitor.java:60)
    at info.magnolia.resourceloader.jcr.JcrResourceOrigin$1.onEvent(JcrResourceOrigin.java:330)
    at info.magnolia.cms.util.ObservationUtil$ObservationBasedDelayedExecutor$1.run(ObservationUtil.java:253)
    at info.magnolia.cms.util.DelayedExecutor$RunnableWrapper.run(DelayedExecutor.java:103)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.ClockDaemon$RunLoop.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am very puzzled by the path structure and by the reason why the resource loader tries to resolve this path.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error. IMHO it is really a Magnolia 5.4 bug (5.4.1 is also affected) that is only encountered on Windows, due to its file system nature.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [MAGNOLIA-6333](https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-6333) to me. Nothing much you can do right now until this issue is fixed. OTOH from the report in jira it looks like publishing still works. Is it same for you? If not, what exactly are you trying to publish?

Comment: the issue is created by me. :-)

Comment: Lol, sorry if you use different names in different places, it's hard to connect the dots. From what I can tell, resource loader is for some reason trying to use identifier of a version of content and use it to locate file in the file system. Why? No clue, but it can't succeed even if path was valid. However I failed to reproduce the same issue so it would help if you can provide some steps on how to reproduce it. Does it happen when publishing content that is part of the demo or just your own? On final version of 5.4 or on some earlier milestone build? ...

Comment: 5.4 is on release version if you try to download Magnolia bundle (no poms no parents just their bundled demo with tomcat). 

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Installing+Magnolia#InstallingMagnolia-DownloadMagnolia

This produced this same error which I get when configuring my project via maven with parent bundle. So I can understand that I screwed up somewhere but I don't understand how official pre-built application can have this stacktrace. In fact I don't even have a reference to valid working build for 5.4 so I struggle to fix it. I may try to run this on lubuntu..

Comment: In the mean time ... upgrade to cache module 5.4.2 (and whole Magnolia to 5.4.1) ... both can be found on http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com. Alternatively, using Java 8 instead of Java 7 on Windows should prevent that error too.